# Detect Passport MRZ from an image

Tags: java, image-processing

Is there any java SDK, so I can use it to process and detect the MRZ from a pssport image,
Note:
For all guys who don't have a clue about MRZ, please read this article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_passport

Answer (score 1):

There is not yet a single library for this use-case.

However if you plug together to optical character recognizer lib [Tesseract OCR](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) (which reads characters from an image) to [MRZ-Java](https://code.google.com/p/mrz-java/) (which parses MRZ string and breaks to its components), the problem is solved.